# Microservices allocation and using kubernetes namespaces for multi tenant applications

Tags: kubernetes, architecture, microservices

We are trying to choose schema for allocation microservices in multi tenant application. We want to use kubernates and see two cases:

First case:

+ Looks like a more productive scheme 
+ Easy to administer 
- Difficult to implement

[image]

Second case:

+ More incapsulated 
- Looks like a less productive scheme

[image]

Comment: why is the second alternative _less productive_ ? and why is the first alternative easy to administer when you write it is more manual?

Comment: @Jonas 1. We must always create a new service's container for each tenant. Although if load is low we could use one general container for all tenants 2. We have single entry point for detect errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the *second case* with a separate namespace per tenant.

**Different configurations**

You have designed a solution with a separate database for each tenant. You can run the same *container image* for the tenants but the should use **different configurations** e.g. they have different address to the database. See [Twelve factor - externalize configuration](https://12factor.net/config).

> We must always create a new service's container for each tenant. Although if load is low we could use one general container for all tenants

You can easily create the same service for each tenant using Kubernetes **declarative** Deployment manifests. You can also assign only the resources that is needed for each tenant, e.g. variations in number of replicas or different CPU or Memory resources.

**Route error information to a central service**

> We have single entry point for detect errors

You should always route observability information, e.g. logs, metrics and events to a central service for your cluster.

**Isolate tenants**

In addition, if you have separate namespaces for tenants, you can isolate them more using [Network Policies](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/network-policies/)

Comment: Also you can patch and upgrade tenants one-at-time, Manage and monitor resources, etc.